# Python transpose dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, transpose

I have

```
data_dict = {1: {'One': 110, 'Two': 210, 'three': 310},
             2: {'One': 120, 'Two': 220, 'three': 320},
             3: {'One': 130, 'Two': 230, 'three': 330}}
```

need to print as CSV in this order

```
'',1,2,3
One,110,120,130
Two,210,220,230
Three,310,320,330
```

No idea how to do it spent hours trying totally exhausted.
I need pure python solution without using Numpy Transpose, Itertools etc

Comment: That CSV is a strange representation of the data in the dictionary.

Comment: @jarmod sometimes CSV and excel can be used not to store data, but to present it as report so its visually faster to see and compare with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous ways to do this. The simplest is probably to create an intermediate dictionary.

Something like this:

```
data_dict = {1: {'One': 110, 'Two': 210, 'three': 310},
             2: {'One': 120, 'Two': 220, 'three': 320},
             3: {'One': 130, 'Two': 230, 'three': 330}}

temp_dict = {"''": list(data_dict.keys())}

for value in data_dict.values():
    for k, v in value.items():
        temp_dict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

for k, v in temp_dict.items():
    print(k, *v, sep=",")
```

**Output:**

```
'',1,2,3
One,110,120,130
Two,210,220,230
three,310,320,330
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

data_dict = {1: {'One': 110, 'Two': 210, 'three': 310},
             2: {'One': 120, 'Two': 220, 'three': 320},
             3: {'One': 130, 'Two': 230, 'three': 330}}

data = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
data.to_csv('data.csv')
print(data)
```

output

```
         1    2    3
One    110  120  130
Two    210  220  230
three  310  320  330
```

Comment: One of requirements was to not use any third party frameworks.